# Android app uploaded in Device Farm via AWS SDK for Go never changed status from INITIALIZED

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to use AWS SDK for Go to automate app runs in AWS Device Farm. But any app that uploaded with Go version of SDK never changed status from "INITIALIZED". If I upload them via AWS Console web UI, then all will be fine.

**Example of code for upload:**

`func uploadApp(client *devicefarm.DeviceFarm, appType, projectArn string) string {
    params := &devicefarm.CreateUploadInput{
        Name:       aws.String(*appName),
        ProjectArn: aws.String(projectArn),
        Type:       aws.String(appType),
    }
    resp, err := client.CreateUpload(params)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to upload an app because of: ", err.Error())
    }
    log.Println("Upload ARN:", *resp.Upload.Arn)
    return *resp.Upload.Arn
}`

**In response I got something like:**

`{
  Upload: {
    Arn: "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:091463382595:upload:c632e325-266b-4bda-a74d-0acec1e2a5ae/9fbbf140-e377-4de9-b7df-dd18a21b2bca",
    Created: 2016-01-15 14:27:31 +0000 UTC,
    Name: "app-debug-unaligned.apk",
    Status: "INITIALIZED",
    Type: "ANDROID_APP",
    Url: "bla-bla-bla"
  }
}`

With time status never changes from "INITIALIZED". As I mentioned, apps which run scheduled from UI works fine.

How to figure it out reason of this ?

=======================================

#### Solution:

1) After `CreateUpload` it requires to upload a file using pre-signed S3 link in the response
2) Upload should be executed via HTTP PUT request by received URL with file content in the body
3) In `&devicefarm.CreateUploadInput` should be specified `ContentType`parameter. For PUT request same value for `Content-Type` header should be used
4) If PUT request will be send from Go code, then `Content-Length` header should be set manually

Comment: can you provide the solution code

Comment: Something like that: https://gist.github.com/artemnikitin/d8caa2862c0b7762064f5fec39804f91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the CreateUpload API, Device Farm will return an "Upload" response containing a "Url" field.

`{
  Upload: {
    Arn: "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:....",
    Created: 2016-01-15 14:27:31 +0000 UTC,
    Name: "app-name.apk",
    Status: "INITIALIZED",
    Type: "ANDROID_APP",
    Url: "bla-bla-bla"
  }
}`

The returned url, "bla-bla-bla", is a pre-signed S3 url for you to upload your application. Documentation on using a pre-signed url to upload an object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Once your application has been uploaded, the app will be processed. The status of your upload will change to "PROCESSING" and "SUCCEEDED" (or "FAILED" if something is wrong). Once it's in "SUCCEEDED" status, you can use it to schedule a run.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. It was really unclear, that I need to use pre-signed URL. But it still don't work for me. 
Based on your link I should send a simple HTTP PUT request with file in body. I do that and in response I got HTTP 403 with an error 
```<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Comment: If in `&devicefarm.CreateUploadInput` specify `ContentType: aws.String("application/octet-stream")` and set the same header in the PUT request after, then error will be different:
HTTP 501
`<Code>NotImplemented</Code><Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>`

Comment: I figured it out. As described here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/467. It requires to manually set Content-Length value. After it all working fine.